# access fixed elem when using $(fixedElem).on(event, dynamicElem, func)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have dynamic elements that need listeners you do something like this:

```
$(fixedElem).on(event, dynamicElem, function(e){
    // Here 'this' is the dynamicElem that the event fired on
});
```

How can I get the `fixedElem` that the listener was added to?

Comment: I'm not sure you can dynamically. Do you have a use case? Maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event.delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/):

```
$(fixedElem).on("event", "dynamicElem", function(e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget);  // Here, fixedElem will be logged.
});
```